# Как поместить данные в буфер, а потом их записать в файл?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать следующий алгоритм на VS C++.
Программа считывает быстро поступающие бинарные данные и помещает их в буфер, после подачи сигнала записывает полученные данные из буфера в файл.
Подскажите хотя бы какие функции использовать.

Comment: Откуда бинарные данные быстро поступают?

Comment: с платы сбора данных

Comment: ftStatus = FT_Read(ftHandle, byInputBuffer, dwNumBytesToRead, &dwNumBytesRead);
   /* byInputBuffer - буфер приянтых данных
   dwNumBytesToRead - кол-во считывемых байт
   dwNumBytesRead - фактическое кол-во прочитанных байт
   */
   printf("dwNumBytesToRead %d bytes/sec\n", dwNumBytesToRead);
   printf("dwNumBytesRead)  %d bytes/sec\n", dwNumBytesRead);
   if (ftStatus == FT_OK ){
    file.write((char*)byInputBuffer, dwNumBytesToRead);
   }

Comment: у меня идет запись сразу в файл, а это занимает много времени.

Comment: Ну да, в файл писать - одна из самых медленных вещей. А Вы можете ограничить сверху, сколько байт вам точно хватить до записи? Тогда заведите массив этого размера и пока этот сигнал не придет (придется наверно каждый раз массив пробегать в поисках команды?) складывать все в этот буфер, потом соответственно писать. Либо, возможно, создать отдельный поток/процесс для записи?

Comment: @Александр имеющийся код нужно добавить в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Принимайте данные с девайса в одном потоке а пишите в другом, работайте с семафорами и критическими секциями, взводите семафор на каждую полученную запись от девайса, и слушайте этот семафор в потоке записи в файл. Так вы будете не зависеть от чтения из буфера и от записи в файл, тоесть два потока будут выполнятся параллельно